# Move menu to middle

Tags: css

I want to move the menu to the middle. How can i do that?

I've tried to change float but it didnt work.

```
ul#menu {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    background-color:#D60024;
}

ul#menu > li {
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    padding:3px;
    border:1px #8a0505 solid;
    background-color:#D60024;
    color:white;
}

ul#menu > li:hover {
    background:#8a0505;
    color:white;
}

ul#menu > li:hover ul {
    opacity:1;
    left:0;
    height:auto;
}

ul#menu li ul {
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:0;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 0;
    margin:0;
    opacity:0;
}

ul#menu ul li {
    background-color:#D60024;
    border:1px #8a0505 solid; 
}

ul#menu ul li:hover {
    background:#8a0505;
    border:1px #8a0505 solid;
    color:white;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sTQLh/13/)

EDIT: I want it like this, but with the same height on the sides. Solved it by padding:4px; on ul#menu.

[JSFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/sTQLh/17/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sTQLh/16/)

I remove the `ul#menu` float and background, and then add the text-align

```
ul#menu {
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    /* background-color:#D60024; */
}
```

and I also remove the `ul#menu > li`  `float:left`

Hope to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to have it like this http://jsfiddle.net/sTQLh/17/   but with the same height on the sides.

Comment: You're welcome. sorry remove the background-color at first. but it's glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to try the [css menu builder](http://swimbi.com) , with many layouts and beautiful menu designs.